# Can I provide methods that use generic types where the generic type is always the class?

Tags: java, generics, subclassing

I'm not sure if I convey the question well enough and I couldn't find a better way to do this, as I am quite new to java.

I believe the best is by way of illustration, if I have a class

```
public abstract class Genome
{
    abstract public Genome randomize();
    abstract public Genome mutate();
    abstract public Genome crossOver(Genome genome);
}
```

Can I make sure that its subclasses would always implement by using generics

```
public class GenomeSubclass extends Genome
{
    public GenomeSubclass randomize();
    // etc...
}
```

instead of the abstract methods provided in the contract?

Comment: You haven't shown any generic code in your post.  What you show is known as "covariant return", where the subclass method override can return a subclass of the overridden method return type.  Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: He wants the methods to have the same return Type like the class have that's currently extending the abstract class. Well, I think that's what he wants.

Comment: Fatal: thanks that is what I meant.

Comment: Jim: I haven't shown because that is exactly an answer I look for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal way would be to define it like this:

```
public abstract class Genome<T extends Genome<T>> {
    abstract public T randomize();
    abstract public T mutate();
    abstract public T crossOver(T genome);
}

public class GenomeSubclass extends Genome<GenomeSubclass>
{
    public GenomeSubclass randomize();
    // etc...
}
```

This is the approach used by Comparable (or at least most uses of Comparable) and Enum, too.

Of course, this does not avoid subclassing other subclasses.

---

Edit to detail my comment:

You can't have both

```
class GenomeSubclass extends Genome {
    public GenomeSubclass crossOver(GenomeSubclass other);
}
```

and

```
class GenomeSubSubclass extends GenomeSubclass {
    public GenomeSubclass crossOver(GenomeSubSubclass other);
}
```

while both are implementing the same Genome method. Every subtype of GenomeSubSubclass must implement the `crossOver(GenomeSubclass)` method, and can't restrain the argument further.

Of course, you could provide `GenomeSubclass` with an type parameter of its own:

```
public class GenomeSubclass<T extends GenomeSubclass<T>> extends Genome<GenomeSubclass<T>>
{
    public GenomeSubclass<T> randomize();
    // etc...
}
```

but then you can't really use this class directly without somehow going back to the raw type. (You would have to write `GenomeSubclass<GenomeSubclass<GenomeSubclass<...>>>`, which is not really possible. Or I'm somehow mis-thinking here.)

---

The principle idea here is that every Genome subtype being used as a type parameter `T` would be compatible to all its own subtypes. This means, we could have this:

```
public abstract class GenomeA extends Genome<GenomeA> {}
```

and then

```
public class AImpl1 extends GenomeA {
   public GenomeA randomize();
   public GenomeA mutate();
   public GenomeA crossOver(GenomeA other);
}

public class AImpl2 extends GenomeA {
   public GenomeA randomize();
   public GenomeA mutate();
   public GenomeA crossOver(GenomeA other);
}
```

Comment: It also means that all the different derived classes don't have a common base class.

Comment: Doing this does not allow a derived class of GenomeSubclass to have it own methods.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Java doesn't have a `This` type, in contrast to `this` object.

Simulating `This` through generic tricks can be done, but it's too nasty. I'd rather never do it.

Now, why do you need it? The only known usage is for method chaining. If you have a different use case, do tell, that would be very interesting.

If it's only for method chaining, I personally don't consider the lack of `This` a big deal.

**EDIT**: the `crossover(This)` is an interesting subject.

Say we have super class `G`, and subclasses `A` and `B`. Suppose `A` can only `crossover(A)`, and `B` only with `B`. Is the `crossover` operation a common operation on `G`?

Not in our type system. Sure we may consider the two `crossover()` related, but that relation cannot be expressed in our type system. Requirement that `X` must declare a method `crossover(X)` cannot be enforced. (Generics can't enforce it either; think `X extends G<Y>`)

Here it's necessary to go "extralinguistic", use another language (English) and another compiler (our eyeballs) to express and enforce the relation. Or, invent a new static analyzer armed with syntax capable of expressing such relations. Runtime reflection may be needed to perform unusual method dispatching.

Probably something like this:

```
/** verbal contract: subclass X must declare method `X crossover(X)` **/
class G

    // no explicit crossover() declaration in G

    static <X extends G> X crossover(X x1, X x2)
        X1 = x1.getClass(), X2 = x2.getClass();
        check: X2 is assignable to X1
        check: X1 has method `X1 crossover(X1)`
        invoke dynamic x1.crossover(x2)

class A

    A crossover(A)
```

Comment: I think the Genome example is already quite good - you want to have (for example) an DNAGenome and an RNAGenome class, which each could be mutated to create new ones, and crossed over with others of the same kind, but not with ones from other types.

Comment: I don't actually know what the Java paradigm is when it comes to this kind of things. For example an instance of a derived class of Genome can cross over with an instance of the same derived class, and crossing over would often require knowledge of the methods to invoke from the derived class.

Comment: @Paŭlo @Adam crossover indeed pushes the envelope. see my understanding in the edit.